# Array with subarray loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Is it possible to create an array and loop through it in JavaScript like below?

```
<?php
$options = array(
    'color' => array('blue', 'yellow', 'white'), 
    'size' => array('39', '40', '41'),
);

foreach($options as $option => $values){
    echo $option.'<br>';
    foreach($values as $value){
        echo $value.' ';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

I checked the internet but I can not find a good example.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Hum... This is php, not JS

Comment: And yes, it's possible to loop through nested arrays in JS, however, Internet is filled with such examples, I doubt you couldn't find good examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly

```js
let options = {
    color: ['blue', 'yellow', 'white'],
    size: [39, 40, 41]
};
```

You have three ways to do this:

**FOR**

```js
for (option in options) {
    console.log(option);
    var values = options[option];
    for (let i = 0, len = values.length, value = values[i]; i < len; value = values[++i]) {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

**ARRAY FOREACH**

```js
for (option in options) {
    console.log(option);
    options[option].forEach(value => {
        console.log(value);
    });
}
```

*Easiest way:* **jQuery**

```js
$.each(options, (option, values) => {
    console.log(option);
    $.each(values, (key, value) => {
        console.log(value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in javascript have integer keys (indexes). You can use an object as you need to store string keys on the parent level and the values can be arrays as they don't have any string keys

```js
const options = {
  color: ['blue', 'yellow', 'white'],
  size: ['39', '40', '41'],
}

Object.entries(options).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key)
  value.forEach(el => console.log(el))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want a javascript equivalent to the php code you've given?

If so, it could be achieved the following way:

```js
let options = {
    color: ['blue', 'yellow', 'white'],
    size: [39, 40, 41]
};

for(option of Object.keys(options)) {
    console.log(option);
    
    for(value of options[option]) {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

this is not exactly the same as your php code, but the loop works in a similar way.